# How to make this TOP Query fast in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

This is my query:

```
 SELECT top 1 w.WONumber, * FROM TSP_TSR_Job t  left join
 wsm_WorkOrderSchedule w on w.tsrjobid = t.JobId WHERE t.JobID=325809
```

Execution plan:
[image]

What I have tried:

```
DECLARE @i INT  
SET @i=1  
SELECT TOP (@i) ObjectType='Job',w.WONumber,*
FROM TSP_TSR_Job t
 left HASH  join wsm_WorkOrderSchedule w 
on w.tsrjobid = t.JobId
 WHERE t.JobID=325809
```

Execution plan:
[image]
Problem is that it's taking 0:0:1 sec for both queries.

2493073 rows in wsm_WorkOrderSchedule and 524444 in TSP_TSR_Job 
brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByXUickKQ Execution plan

```
> SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time =
> 0 ms.
> 
>  SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
> Warning: The join order has been enforced because a local join hint is
> used. SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 5 ms, elapsed
> time = 5 ms.
> 
> (1 row(s) affected) Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0,
> physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
> physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'Worktable'. Scan
> count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob
> logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. Table
> 'wsm_WorkOrderSchedule'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6, physical reads
> 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
> read-ahead reads 0. Table 'TSP_TSR_Job'. Scan count 0, logical reads
> 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob
> physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
> 
> (1 row(s) affected)
> 
>  SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 11
> ms. SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed
> time = 1 ms.
> 
>  SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 1 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
```

---

Comment: There is an index recommendation in green.

Comment: `wsm_WorkOrderSchedule` misses index on join column. Which was already told you by SSMS on second screenshot.

Comment: What do the *indexes* look like? Trying to change how join works won't help if the correct indexes are missing. The `wsm_WorkOrderSchedule.tsrjobid` and `TSP_TSR_Job .JobId` fields should appear in indexes on both tables.

Comment: You have an an exclamation mark over your CIX scan in both plans. Whats the detail on that?

Comment: FIeld order matters in a string. `tsrjobid` should be the first field on an index to be of use.

Comment: Note, your TOP 1 is missing `ORDER BY` clause so it may result with random output each time.

Comment: How many rows in wsm_WorkOrderSchedule?

Comment: 2493073 rows in wsm_WorkOrderSchedule and 524444 in TSP_TSR_Job

Comment: I would add the recommended index then, that would save you scanning 2.5 million rows!

Comment: Also, you are using `SELECT *`, you should only be selecting the columns you need so you can include them in your index on `TSP_TSR_Job`.

Comment: could you copy the execution plan XML and paste into pastetheplan.com and give us the link so we can actually check out what's happening under the hood?

Comment: I would check that `wsm_WorkOrderSchedule` has a nonclustered index on `tsrjobid` column. I believe that is why the `Warning` icon is on the Clustered Index Scan operator. Other than that, your current SQL query is fine. Maybe you could re-check if bringing back all the columns with the `*` is really required. If not, then bring back only the columns you need.

Comment: @RichBenner https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByXUickKQ

Comment: After looking at the plan, you should definitely limit your query to selecting only the columns you need, get rid of that `SELECT *`

Comment: any other possible solution beside that ? @MJH

Comment: Are you saying that you NEED all those columns?

Comment: yes mate need all col.  @MJH

Comment: Hmmm, ok, can you `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`, run the query and add the output to your question?

Comment: @MJH I HAVE ADDED

Comment: There does not seem to be much wrong with performance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create an index to remove clustered index scan:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_wsm_WorkOrderSchedule_tsrjobid
    ON wsm_WorkOrderSchedule (tsrjobid)
    INCLUDE (WONumber);
```

Also, alter your `TSP_TSR_JobId` index to have included columns. Look at key lookup operator to find out which columns are needed

Comment: why WOnumber included ?

Comment: @nikhiljain because it is in your `SELECT` statement. Included column are included in the leaf node of the indexed and are pretty much useful for this case - when you just want to ouput that column and not query by it.

Comment: It won't really help that much if he has a `*` operator.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Ah crap, you're correct. I didn't notice that he uses * for both tables, not just for `TSP_TSR_Job`. Query probably has to be rewritten and column names revealed. Having `SELECT *` is already considered quite a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add a nonclustered index on the `wsm_WorkOrderSchedule` (*which it seems you have*):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NC_wsm_WorkOrderSchedule_tsrjobid 
ON wsm_WorkOrderSchedule (tsrjobid);
```

By adding this index, you'll get the best possible execution plan for your particular query (*where you seem to **really need** all the columns, as you say*).

Now, your expectation is that your query should take less than 1 second (*which you think it does at this point*).

But actually, by looking at the information from your `STATISTICS TIME` output, your query only takes about 18ms **to execute** (and there is am important distinction to be made).

The rest up to the 1 second you're **presumably** looking at in SQL Server Management Studio on the bottom right of the screen, is actually the time required for the data to pass through the network and for SSMS to render it.

**Edit:**

*If you're curious where I came up with the 18ms, it's easy to just go to [statisticsparser.com](http://statisticsparser.com) and post in the text output of your STATISTICS TIME and IO in there and parse. You'll get a nice visual brakedown of your times and other resource usage by table.*